\nolimits but only on top or at the bottom
I'm trying to typeset a sum with subscript being below the sum symbol (as default for display style sum), but the superscript appearing as if \nolimits is present (in the top right corner). Is there any simple way to do that? Notice that writing simply {\sum_{lower}}^{upper} doesn't work: if the subscript is too long, it will push the superscript to the right, which is not what I intend (if the subscript is shorter than \sum itself, it works fine).
How can this be solved? And what about an analogous question with subscript and superscript swapped?

Sorry to ask, can you show your exact requirement as in image format? As I couldn't able to understand it correctly.

I think OP is looking for \sum_{lower} combined with \sum\nolimits^{upper}.  The stated {\sum_{lower}}^{upper} does this, but {\sum_{really long lower}}^{upper} doesn't.

I guess you want \sideset. Look into the manual of amsmath

\sideset is precisely what I needed. Thank you @egreg
